# How to set a approval for build in Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

How to set a approval for build in Azure devops, After approval only build should be executed.

I need to set a approval for build in azure devops, Like How we set a approval for Deployments in azure devops.

Comment: Are you using classic or YAML pipelines?

Comment: Currently am using Classic, orelse is it possible in yaml pipeline

Comment: How to set a approval for build in yaml in Azure devops ?                                                                               I know its available for deployment process but I want to know the approval set up for build in yaml

Comment: Please review the answers. Several people (myself included) have explained what is and is not possible and how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in classic pipelines. However, YAML pipelines eliminates the distinction between "build" and "release", so you can achieve your objective by treating your build like a deployment.

You can create a "Build" environment, assign a required approver to the environment as an environment check, and use a [`deployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) job, even though technically no deployment is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel said you need to specify and create an environment and define your approvals on that environment.

[image]

Then you can define your deployment job on that environment.

```
  jobs:
  - deployment: job1
    displayName: job1
    environment: myenv
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: run powershell 1
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                Write-Host "Hello from powershell 1"
```

Attaching documentation article:

https://blog.geralexgr.com/devops/create-approvals-on-build-and-release-azure-devops-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You have to create repository branch with approval policies, like to check-in code to that branch minimum number of approval required and link the build process with that target branch. So once you raise PR automatically build triggered and halted for approval. Once approval in place then only build will complete and merged to target branch.
Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies-overview?view=azure-devops

[image: Project Settings]
[image: branch settings]